# How to modify build rules in Makefile

Tags: compiling, gcc, ffmpeg, c, makefile

I tried to compile FFmpeg from source code located [HERE](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg). All is good, but the built binaries lack `ffplay`. And looks like the build rule is missing from the makefile located under `/fftools`.

How can I modify the makefile(s) to also build ffplay, alongside with ffmpeg and ffprobe?

Comment: Usual culprit is omitting the 'development' libraries for sdl. However you would be better overall to follow from here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu Note the dependency on libsdl2-dev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to modify any `Makefile`.

## `ffplay`

`ffplay` requires sdl2, so install the libsdl2-dev package to fulfill that dependency. You won't need `--enable-ffplay` as it is enabled automatically.

## Your other `./configure` line options

- `--enable-pthreads` Remove this. It is auto enabled.
- `--enable-libvpx` requires libvpx-dev package.
- `--enable-libmp3lame` requires  libmp3lame-dev package.
- `--enable-libtheora` requires libtheora-dev, but I would omit it and use libvpx instead.
- `--enable-libvorbis` requires libvorbis-dev, but I would omit it and use libopus instead.
- `--enable-libx264` requires libx264-dev.
- `--enable-libx265` requires libx265-dev.
- `--enable-runtime-cpudetect` no need for this unless you're building an executable that will run on various machines.
- `--enable-libfdk-aac` requires libfdk-aac-dev.
- `--enable-avfilter` Remove this as it is automatically enabled.
- `--enable-libopencore_amrwb` `--enable-libopencore_amrnb` Old, legacy encoders/decoders that nobody uses anymore. Requires libopencore-amrnb-dev and libopencore-amrwb-dev. If you remove this then you can remove `--enable-version3`.
- `--enable-filters` Remove this as it is automatically enabled.
- `--enable-libvidstab` Requires libvidstab-dev.
- `--enable-libaom` Requires a recent libaom-dev. You may have to compile it if your repo version is too old.
- `--enable-libxcb` Requires libxcb1-dev, libxcb-shm0-dev, and libxcb-xfixes0-dev. You can omit declaring this option as it is automatically detected and enabled.
- `--enable-gnutls` Requires libgnutls-dev or libgnutls28-dev depending on your Ubuntu version.

## Compile guide

If you don't want to have to guess what to install just follow [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu).

Comment: Great explanation, and it works! Thanks. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Required libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake build-essential cmake git-core libass-dev libfreetype6-dev libsdl2-dev libtool libva-dev libvdpau-dev   libvorbis-dev libxcb1-dev libxcb-shm0-dev libxcb-xfixes0-dev pkg-config  texinfo  wget zlib1g-dev
```

To build depency for aom which requires recent version than the one in the repo:

```
git clone https://aomedia.googlesource.com/aom
cd aom
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=1 ..
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

To build `ffmpeg`:

```
  wget -O ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2 https://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
  tar xjvf ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2
  cd ffmpeg/
```

You  need to run `./configure` script in the source directory before you run `make`. I used the following flags to set the options:

```
 ./configure --prefix=/usr/local  --enable-shared  --disable-debug  --enable-ffplay  --disable-doc  --enable-gpl  --enable-version3  --enable-nonfree  --enable-pthreads  --enable-libvpx  --enable-libmp3lame  --enable-libtheora  --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264  --enable-libx265  --enable-runtime-cpudetect  --enable-libfdk-aac  --enable-avfilter  --enable-libopencore_amrwb  --enable-libopencore_amrnb  --enable-filters --enable-libvidstab  --enable-libaom  --enable-libxcb --enable-gnutls
```

For complete list of options:

```
 ./configure --help
```

Comment: ERROR: gnutls not found using pkg-config

Comment: I remember first time, I just ran `./configure`

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libgnutls-dev`

Comment: For a clean build run `make distclean` before running `configure` script.

Comment: Well, I just added `--enable-ffplay` which looks the missing part. But ffplay was not produced. Basically, I ran `./configure --prefix=/usr/local  --enable-shared  --disable-debug  --enable-ffplay`

Comment: Did you build and install it running `make`, `sudo make install` respectively?

Comment: Yes I did that. The ffprobe and ffmpeg appeared under `/FFmpeg`, but not ffplay.

Comment: btw, I didn't find `enable-ffplay` in the help. Only `  --disable-ffplay` is there. So I'm guessing building ffplay is enabled by default.

Comment: what is the output of `which ffplay`?

Comment: I don't have ffplay currently. So no output!

Comment: I think due to interdependencies it fails. You need to add those options I posted.

Comment: And now complains : `ERROR: aom >= 1.0.0 not found using pkg-config`

Comment: I can get many of such errors. Is there to know the exact apt-get library name for those?